# How to return an nvarchar(max) in a CLR UDF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, nvarchar

Assuming following definition:

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces each occurrence of sPattern in sInput with sReplace. This is done 
/// with the CLR: 
/// new RegEx(sPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline).Replace(sInput, sReplace). 
/// The result of the replacement is the return value.
/// </summary>
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
public static  SqlString FRegexReplace(string sInput, string sPattern, 
      string sReplace)
{
    return new Regex(sPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline).Replace(sInput, sReplace);
}
```

Passing in a `nvarchar(max)` value for `sInput` with a length > 4000 will result in the value being truncated (i.e. the result of calling this UDF is `nvarchar(4000)` as opposed to `nvarchar(max)`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Oh, whatever, I found the answer myself:

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces each occurrence of sPattern in sInput with sReplace. This is done 
/// with the CLR: 
/// new RegEx(sPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline).Replace(sInput, sReplace). 
/// The result of the replacement is the return value.
/// </summary>
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
[return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]
public static  SqlString FRegexReplace([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]string sInput, 
       string sPattern, string sReplace)
{
    return new Regex(sPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline).Replace(sInput, sReplace);
}
```

The idea is to hint to SQL Server that the input and return values are not the default `nvarchar(4000)`, but have a different size.

I learned a new trick regarding attributes: They can be added to the parameters as well as the method itself (quite obvious), but *also* to the return value with the `[return: AttributeName(Parameter=Value, ...)]` Syntax.

Comment: That mechanism is explicitly described in the reference I quoted - the answer you down-voted.

Answer (score 2):

See also [How to create CLR stored procedure with Nvarchar(max) parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213788/how-to-create-clr-stored-procedure-with-nvarcharmax-parameter) where you'll discover how/why you really should use the SqlChars data type.  See [Handling Large Object (LOB) Parameters in the CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/handling-large-object-lob-parameters-in-the-clr) in MSDN.