# How to create CLR stored procedure with Nvarchar(max) parameter?

Tags: sql-server, types, sqldatatypes, sqlclr

Is it possible to create CLR stored procedure in SQL Server CLR project having input parameterof type nvarchar(max)?

If you define stored procedure:

> <Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure()> _
>  Public Shared
>   Sub MyProcedure(ByVal param1 As String)

Then when you deploy it, param1 is of type NVarchar(4000). Is there a way to have it NVarchar(max)?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `SqlFacet` attribute. If you want the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` type as a parameter, then you should do this:

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static void storedProcedure1([SqlFacet(MaxSize=-1)] String param){ .. }
```

If you need it as a return value in a user defined function:

```
[return:SqlFacet(MaxSize=-1)]
[SqlFunction]
public static String userFunction1(){ ... }
```

The `MaxSize=-1` indicates that the size of the `NVARCHAR` will be `MAX`.

Answer (score 6):

Define your parameter to be of type [SqlChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlchars.aspx), instead of string. See [Handling Large Object Parameters in the CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131065.aspx)

Comment: Hi Damien. Through no fault of your own, this answer is now obsolete and meaningless. It was only that early versions of Visual Studio / SSDT had defaulted `SqlChars` to map to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and `SqlString` to map to `NVARCHAR(4000)`. Starting in at least VS 2012, I think both `SqlString` and `SqlChars` map to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. Also, even in those early days, the preferred method of indicating the T-SQL datatype options was via the `SqlFacet` attribute (as shown in [Guillermo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748786/577765)).