# CLR function will not return more than 4000 chars

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, sqlclr

first time posting, please be kind! :-)
New to VB/C#, Trying to fix up a CLR function that calls a web service. I've cobbled together the following:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;

// For the SQL Server integration
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

// Other things we need for WebRequest
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{

// Function to return a web URL as a string value.
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]

public static SqlChars GET(SqlString uri, SqlString username, SqlString passwd)
{
    // The SqlPipe is how we send data back to the caller
    SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
    SqlChars document;

    // Set up the request, including authentication
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Convert.ToString(uri));
    if (Convert.ToString(username) != null & Convert.ToString(username) != "")
    {
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            Convert.ToString(username),
            Convert.ToString(passwd));
    }
    ((HttpWebRequest)req).UserAgent = "CLR web client on SQL Server";

    // Fire off the request and retrieve the response.
    // We'll put the response in the string variable "document".
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    document = new SqlChars(rdr.ReadToEnd());
    if (document.IsNull)
    {
        return SqlChars.Null;
    }

    // Close up everything...
    rdr.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    resp.Close();

    // .. and return the output to the caller.
    return (document);
}
```

This will only return 4000 characters even though it is coded for sqlChars. The API call could potentially return upwards of 14MB during a full inventory pull.  If I understand correctly sqlChars goes to varchar(max) (or nvarchar(max)) ...
What am I missing here? compiled for .Net 3.0 on sql server 2005 if that helps...
Andy

Comment: See whether `resp.StatusCode` = 206 instead of 200.

Comment: Try `new SqlChars(rdr.ReadToEnd().ToCharArray())`. If that works, I'll make an answer for it.

Comment: On a side note, you probably [don't want to use `WebRequest` from inside a CLR procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752357/sql-server-2008-how-crash-safe-is-a-clr-stored-procedure-that-loads-unmanaged-l#comment60595563_36493550).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create CLR stored procedure with Nvarchar(max) parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213788/how-to-create-clr-stored-procedure-with-nvarcharmax-parameter)

Comment: Status is 200 OK. ToCharArray returned the same 4000 chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `SqlChars` nor `SqlString` are necessarily tied to either `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(4000)`. In .NET, a `string` is `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and so both `SqlChars` and `SqlString` can map to both `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(4000)`. The only thing that determines whether it is `MAX` or `4000` (or technically `1` through `4000`) is the datatype declared for the input parameter, return type, or result set column in the `CREATE [PROCEDURE | FUNCTION | AGGREGATE]` statement. So, you first need to check there. It is clearly defined as `NVARCHAR(4000)`. If you simply change it (i.e. `ALTER FUNCTION`) to be `NVARCHAR(MAX)` it will return everything.

Some other notes:

1. The SQLCLR API only allows for `NVARCHAR`, not `VARCHAR`.
2. If you are using Visual Studio / SSDT, you can decorate your method to provide a hint for the SSDT DDL generation process that will tell it to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. You do that by adding the following above the `[SqlFunction()]` decorator:

   ```
   [return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]
   ```

   Had you wanted the return type to be `NVARCHAR(250)`, you would use `MaxSize = 250`.
3. You need to be *very* careful when using external resources in this manner within SQLCLR. The AppDomain can stay loaded for a long time and is shared by all Sessions. So if you have an exception and there is no `using()` construct and no `try ... finally` in which you call `Dispose()` on the opened resource(s), then you can be orphaning those handles for a long time. That can result in locking of files (if it's a file system operation) or can use up networking sockets. You need to be *very* thorough in your error handling and resource cleanup here! VERY! I have some other answers here with additional notes, such as: [SQL CLR Web Service Call: Limiting Overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35729337/577765).

   This means that, in its current form, the code shown in the question is *very* risky due to not using either the `using()` construct or `try...catch...finally`. **AND IN FACT, you are already doing a VERY BAD thing by returning `return SqlChars.Null;` *before* the 3 `.Close()` statements. If `document.IsNull` ever returns `true`, then this code will orphan that network connection and those external resources!!!!!**
4. If this UDF will only ever be called by one session / process at a time, and never multiple, then you are ok. Otherwise, you are going to run into the default number of external connections being 2 problem that causes additional connections to wait until one of the two allowed connections closes. In that case, you will need to set the default connection count in the `ServicePointManager` class.
5. There is no reason to call `Convert.ToString({input_parameter})` as you are doing. All `Sql*` types have a `Value` property that returns the passed in value in the expected .NET type. So you would instead simply use `uri.Value` and `username.Value`, etc.
6. There is no reason to have this method attribute property specified:

   ```
   DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read
   ```

   You only specify `Read` if you are making a connection to the DB and accessing data. There is no `SqlConnection` in this code so you don't need this property which is a performance hit. Along those same lines, you also do not need `using System.Data.SqlClient;`.
7. For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please see the list of resources I have posted on [SQLCLR Info](https://SQLCLR.org/)
8. For anyone interested in a fully functional, pre-done implementation of a WebRequest SQLCLR UDF, such a function already exists in the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_50165161) library (that I wrote). The function is named **INET_GetWebPages** and supports passing in all (or at least most) HTTP headers including custom headers, sending POST data, getting back binary data as `VARBINARY`, overriding the default 2 connection per URI maximum, etc. Please note that while most functions are available in the Free version, this particular function is only available in the Full (i.e. paid) version.

Comment: I too thought the function was the issue but here is the code:    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_get_webrequest(
     uri        nvarchar(max),
     user       nvarchar(255)=NULL,
     passwd     nvarchar(255)=NULL
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
EXTERNAL NAME SqlWebRequest.UserDefinedFunctions.GET;

GO    so I'm not sure what to make of it all.

Comment: @A.Guattery are you concatenating the function result with something?

Comment: @A.Guattery While I don't believe that concatenating the return value with anything would lead to this, GSerg does bring up a good point in that we need to see _exactly_ how you are testing this. Please post the `CREATE FUNCTION` T-SQL to the question as well as your test query. Are you storing the return value in an `NVARCHAR(4000)` variable perhaps? How do you know it's only returning 4000 chars? How do you know that more than 4000 are being returned by the remote service?

Comment: @A.Guattery Also, please see my updated answer. I put in some extra notes, including something I just noticed that is _very_ dangerous in your code. Please do not use this code until correcting the flaw (bolded part of Note #3)!

Comment: @SolomonRutzky ... Found It! The return variable was being declared initially as nvarchar(max) but further into the code was being redeclared as nvarchar(4000). So your insight fixed the initial issue. I inherited this mess halfway through, and am trying my best to get this CLR working even with my limited knowledge. I have already deleted the NULL returns; even I know that was bad. I am learning on the fly here but it looks to me like the C#    try...catch...finally    is similar enough to t-sql that I can get it in there properly.

Comment: @A.Guattery Glad you got that part figured out! And I know how frustrating it can be inheriting someone else's mess. Again, please review the resources I linked to in Note # 7. I have several example in my Stairway to SQLCLR series that show proper usage of `using()` and/or `try...catch...finally` (or at least I better!). Good luck!