# Base64 encode a utf8 string in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, string, utf-8, base64

I have an SQL function for converting a string to a base64-encoded string. The only problem is is that UTF8 is not being used, which I can tell because I have a seperate C# tool that gives a different output.

SQL Function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Base64Encode] ( @sInput NVARCHAR(max) )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
BEGIN

DECLARE @vInput              VARBINARY(max)
DECLARE @sEncodedOutput      NVARCHAR(max)

set @vInput = convert(varbinary(max), @sInput)
set @sEncodedOutput = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@vInput"))', 'NVARCHAR(max)')

RETURN @sEncodedOutput

END
```

C#

```
        try
        {
            encodedValueTextbox.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(valueTextbox.Text));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            encodedValueTextbox.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Is there a way to get SQL to use UTF8?

Comment: While I can't anwer your question, I am wondering why you want to base64 encode a UFT-8 string? Do you try to hide the text? If you want so, better go with encryption.

Comment: The 'random text' look that base64 gives is sufficient

Comment: @GameScripting: You can't base-64 encode an nvarchar value as there are more than 256 character codes, so the text has to be encoded into byte format, for example using UTF-8.

Comment: A MSSQL `NVarChar` is not a .Net `string`. A MSSQL `VarBinary` is not a .Net `byte[]`. A TSQL conversion to from `NVarChar` to `VarBinary` is not a call to the .Net `UTF8.GetBytes()` function. A TSQL cast to an XML `NVarChar` is not a call to the .Net `Convert.ToBase64String()`. So, what you makes you think the operations should be equivalent? Do you want to round trip the values using functions from both platforms?

Comment: @Jodrell: I am not sure what your point is? Yes I understand the datatypes differ between languages, but as I am not as proficient in SQL as I am C#, I am asking how can I get SQL to produce the same output as C#.

Comment: I think if what I am reading is correct; SQL Server doesn't support UTF8? I was hoping to be able to do something like `convert(varbinary(max), @sInput, UTF8)` or something...

Comment: LynchDev, NVARCHAR is UTF16. You can do this but you need to write your own UTF-8 encoding `create function dbo.NVarCharToUTF8(@s nvarchar(max))
returns varbinary(max) as....`

Comment: My point is. If the TSQL approach round trips, does it matter if the results differ from some other method?

Comment: @Jodrell has a point. Why not change the C# method to use UTF-16 to match the T-SQL method? Probably easier.

Comment: Still not understanding you @Jodrell; if you're asking if it matters that both methods produce the same output, then yes it does (thus the question!). @Ben I was hoping to not have to do that as it will require taking down the system while we spend time re-encoding our data. As for a NVarCharToUTF8 function - I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: You can do it with a SQL CLR function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx

Comment: See this answer for an example of converting a string to UTF-8: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14041069/1187211

Answer (score 0):

Your @sInput is NVARCHAR, which is UNICODE UCS-2.  So, you're turning UCS-2 into binary.

You could change the input parameter to varbinary and pass in UTF-8 as binary into the function.  If your source data into the function is also nvarchar from SQL, you'll need to keep pushing that binary data conversion back to the source C# (maybe to the point of storage as varbinary, basically I don't know what the rest of your system looks like).

An alternative is to write this function in CLR.  Convert the UCS-2 into UTF-8 using C# and then just do the Base64 encoding there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, in the end I solved it in a way that is as simple as it is subtle.
The issue is that nvarchar is a data type that occupies 2 bytes for each character, consequently if the input or output variable is of type nvarchar the conversion will be done in UTF-16. If both variables are of type varchar (where each character occupies only one byte) the encoding will be done in UTF-8.

Below is your code with the modification.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Base64Encode] ( @sInput VARCHAR(max) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
BEGIN

DECLARE @vInput              VARBINARY(max)
DECLARE @sEncodedOutput      VARCHAR(max)

set @vInput = convert(varbinary(max), @sInput)
set @sEncodedOutput = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@vInput"))', 'VARCHAR(max)')

RETURN @sEncodedOutput

END
```