# How to decode base64 unicode string with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, base64

Can't decode Arabic characters in base64 string.
When I decode it must be like this : 'سلام جیران' (using [base64encode](https://www.base64encode.org/) website). I try to decode like this :

```
SELECT CAST(
          CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary("2LPZhNin2YUg2KzbjNix2KfZhg==")' , 'VARBINARY(MAX)') 
          AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
           ) UnicodeEncoding ;
```

Based on this answer : [Base64 encoding in SQL Server 2005 T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql)
But have response like this : '돘蓙Ꟙ藙�����'
Is there any way to decode Arabic characters correctly?

Comment: The problem is that your binary data is a UTF-8 encoding. But SQL Server nvarchar is UCS-2

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But is there any solution for this situation? Consider that I use a library that encode messages with UTF-8 then I send them for MS SQL Server

Comment: There is some good information in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32859598/9395740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a UTF-8 string to nvarchar, you can use a CLR function (such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14041069/1187211) or a T-SQL function (such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28412587/1187211).

Using the second function, you can decode your data like this:

```
SELECT dbo.DecodeUTF8String(CAST(N'' AS XML).value
('xs:base64Binary("2LPZhNin2YUg2KzbjNix2KfZhg==")','VARBINARY(MAX)'))
```