# How to decode BASE64 text (from JSON data) in TSQL with accents intact

Tags: json, t-sql, base64, decoding, sql-server-2019

I have a table containing chat messages that each contain **text** + **attachments**. These values are combined into an object and then serialized and stored as JSON text in the table. Each attachment consists of two strings: `name` and `oid`, the latter of which is a BASE64 encoded file path.

The original file paths can contain accented characters such as `Privé`.

Example message data, before and after BASE64 encoding:

| text | attachments (not BASE64 encoded) | attachments (BASE64 encoded) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <p>Docs</p> | [ {"name": "doc1.pdf", "path": "Privé\doc1.pdf"} ] | [ {"name": "doc1.pdf", "oid": "UHJpdsOpXGRvYzEucGRm"} ] |

I now want to decode all this in SQL. I got quite far, first using OPENJSON() to convert the stored JSON to a dataset that can be used for JOIN and SELECT, and then using some XML trickery to decode the BASE64 file paths.

Unfortunately I can't get the accented characters right: `Privé` becomes `PrivÃ©`, whatever I do (so far).

**Sample SQL**:

```sql
DECLARE     @messagesTable TABLE([Id] UniqueIdentifier, [Content] NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @messagesTable VALUES(
   'EF69067D-428B-8DA4-4FD8-0004CF6D28C2',
   N'{"text":"<p>Docs</p>","attachments":[{"name":"doc1.pdf","oid":"UHJpdsOpXGRvYzEucGRm"},{"name":"doc2.pdf","oid":"QWxnZW1lZW5cZG9jMi5wZGY="}]}'
)

SELECT      [M].[Id], [J].[name], [J].[oid],
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("[J].[oid]"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)')) AS decodedOid
FROM        @messagesTable AS [M]
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([M].[Content], '$.attachments') WITH ([name] NVARCHAR(MAX), [oid] NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [J]
```

Result:

| Id | name | oid | decodedOid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EF69067D-428B-8DA4-4FD8-0004CF6D28C2 | doc1.pdf | UHJpdsOpXGRvYzEucGRm | PrivÃ©\doc1.pdf |
| EF69067D-428B-8DA4-4FD8-0004CF6D28C2 | doc2.pdf | QWxnZW1lZW5cZG9jMi5wZGY= | Algemeen\doc2.pdf |

**Sample DB Fiddle** - it requires using a regular table instead of a table variable, otherwise the same:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/413383/1

I tried using `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ... )` in the `SELECT` but that made the results become Chinese text or something like that.

I also tried various kinds of COLLATE, both after the `CONVERT(...)` and inside the `WITH(... [oid] NVARCHAR(MAX))` part but it never seemed to change anything.

What change is needed to make this query return **`Privé\doc1.pdf`** for the first attachment?

Comment: You can try to use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50433415/8564731 The original TSQL function is located here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28412587/8564731

Comment: Thanks, I tried the function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68550176/ and it worked.